# Tree with Multiple Children - Linear Time Access Complexity

Tags: algorithm, tree

My problem is not with the structure to hold the Tree but the way I am doing it; because I think this implementation will cost much in long run.

I have a tree structure in which a tree **Node will contain the List of references of its children**. But here the problem is that **while finding the child of a Node, we need to go through the List of children which will take Linear time(Linear time complexity)**. And I also need to store these all as immediate child(as children word is used for the immediate children).

Now, is there any way I can put all the children other than List structure so that the retrieval and deletion of the children from the List will be efficient and logarithmic(if we can)?
[image]

If I am going to traverse the Tree then to go to the right children from the root node, I will have to check a condition for each child node. That check would be **Linear search and check**. 
I just want a technique which will help in improving this algorithm of searching for the right child in the children list during traversal.

Comment: you need to be more descriptive about your data structure, how many children can a node have, is it a by definition tree, or a you using the term tree incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just having each node keep a regular list, have it either keep a sorted list(log n lookup) or a hashmap(constant time lookup). In this case sorting is probably the best so you can easily iterate over the elements and save space.

Comment: That applies in a case where a Node contains a string or int so that I can sort and perform Binary Search/Divide and Conquer algo to find the element in Logarithmic time.

Comment: @MasterJ well your node has to have some sort of data in it, if it has data you can sort it

Comment: Yes, But in my case I am just holding the references of the Nodes which does not have anything to get sorted. 

Creating any priority attribute in the Nodes will diminish my work of holding references that is why I can not have such a sorting element.

Comment: @MasterJ you can pretty much always have a sorting criteria, but once ur talking about references you have to specify a language for further help

Comment: I will add the children dynamically using a UI. 

Like I have selected a Node then then I select its children by dragging and dropping just below it. Doing this parent Node will hold the list of references of all the Nodes added to it.

I will do it this way that is why the references can not have any sorting information.

Comment: @MasterJ well I still don't see why that means you can't sort it, but if your just dragging and dropping these nodes speed isn't gonna matter much

Comment: I think I do need to keep a string with the Node where I will need to implement divide & conquer. Let me implement it.'

Comment: @MasterJ then sort or hash on that